# Trouble passing variable to fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl

I have tried a few different variations of code and the only time I have got it to work is if I disable the tessellation shader.

When I run this code nothing renders....

```
static const GLchar* vertShaderSource[] =
{
    "#version 430 core \n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 offset; \n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec4 color; \n"
    "out vec4 vs_color; \n"
    "void main(void) \n"        
    "{ \n"
    "const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4(0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0),vec4(-0.25,-0.25,0.5,1.0),vec4(0.25,0.25,0.5,1.0)); \n"
    "gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID] + offset; \n"
    "vs_color[gl_VertexID]=color; \n"
    "} \n"
};

//SOURCE FOR TESSALATION CONTROL SHADER
static const GLchar* TCSsource[] = 
{
    "#version 430 core \n"
    "layout (vertices = 3) out; \n"
    "in vec4 vs_color[]; \n"
    "out Tess{ \n"
    "vec4 tcs_color; \n"
    "} Out[]; \n"
    "void main(void) \n"
    "{ \n"
    "if(gl_InvocationID == 0) \n"
    "{ \n"
    "gl_TessLevelInner[0] = 5.0; \n"
    "gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = 5.0; \n"
    "gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = 5.0; \n"
    "gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = 5.0; \n"
    "} \n"
    "gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position; \n"
    "Out[gl_InvocationID].tcs_color = vs_color[gl_InvocationID]; \n"
    "} \n"
};


//SOURCE FOR THE TEESALATION CONTROL SHADER
static const GLchar* TEShaderSource[] =
{
    "#version 430 core \n"
    "layout (triangles,equal_spacing,cw) in; \n"
    "in Tess{ \n"
    "vec4 tcs_color; \n"
    "} In[];"
    "out vec4 tes_color; \n"
    "void main(void) \n"
    "{ \n"
    "gl_Position = (gl_TessCoord.x * gl_in[0].gl_Position + gl_TessCoord.y * gl_in[1].gl_Position + gl_TessCoord.z * gl_in[2].gl_Position); \n"
    "tes_color = In[0].tcs_color; \n"
    "} \n"
};


//SOURCE CODE FOR FRAGMENT SHADER
static const GLchar* fragShaderSource[] =
{
    "#version 430 core \n"
    " \n"
    "in vec4 tes_color; \n"
    "out vec4 color; \n"
    " \n"
    "void main(void) \n"
    "{ \n"
    "color = tes_color; \n"
    "} \n"
};
```

Comment: You should consider loading them from external files instead of having them at your C++ source code. It should save you much of the hassle, makes it very easy to see what line does those compile errors originated, no `\n`s and quotes... it's just the right thing to do.

Comment: In the future you should not delete your questions only to ask the same thing a few days later in another question. I gave you some useful comments in your previous attempt at asking this same question, you could have edited the question. In addition to helping you, these questions help other people (if they are not deleted), because they will appear under the **Related** section.